# Evaluar cadena como expresión en python

Tags: python, evaluación

Quiero hacer un programa con un interfaz simple, he elegido tkinter. He visto que se puede poner un "entrybox" (en tkinter) para que el usuario coloque un número o texto.

¿Se puede hacer una operación dentro de ese cuadro?

Por ejemplo, que el usuario escriba "5x5" y al darle a la tecla enter del teclado se genere el resultado.

Lo que no quiero es que ponga un valor en un cuadro y otro valor en otro cuadro. Si no que dentro del mismo haga la operación.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio  Luigi, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Discusión sobre seguridad

`eval()` es considerado peligroso, sobre todo si lo usas en un servidor para evaluar una expresión que ha sido enviada desde un cliente. Esto jamás debe hacerse pues permite la *inyección de código*, es decir, que el cliente te suministre una cadena que será ejecutada por tu servidor. Piensa que la cadena que el cliente envía puede contener cualquier comando python que se ejecutaría en el servidor, con el consiguiente riesgo de seguridad.

Aunque probablemente no sea tu caso (porque aparentemente se estará ejecutando en la máquina cliente por el propio usuario, en quien confiamos), aún así es pertinente el consejo de no ejecutar con `eval()` cualquier cosa que el usuario pueda darle al programa pues éste puede tener consecuencias no deseables.

## ¿Solución?

Pero si no usamos `eval()` ¿qué usar?

La cosa es más difícil de lo que parece, pues queremos una funcionalidad capaz de evaluar expresiones simples, pero que rechace expresiones más complejas y peligrosas.

En un comentario sugerí el uso de `ast.literal_eval()`, pensando que éste era justamente el método que necesitábamos, pero tras indagar un poco más descubrí que no nos sirve. Este método sólo permite evaluar **literales** (ya su nombre lo advertía :-)), es decir, cosas como `2`, o `3.5`, o `"Una cadena"`, pero no expresiones que impliquen operaciones, como `3/2`, etc.

Curiosamente la suma sí que la permite. `ast.literal_eval('2+1')` retorna 3, pero esto es más bien un *bug*. Los diseñadores de `literal_eval()` admitieron el `+` y el `-` como símbolos válidos porque sin ellos no se podrían introducir números complejos como `1+3j`, que son literales válidos en python.

## ¿Entonces?

Python no da solución a este problema, aunque da las herramientas para poder programar de forma relativamente simple una solución. En el módulo [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) hay un parser genérico que analiza cualquier expresión por complicada que sea que se le pase dentro de una cadena (por ejemplo: `"3**(2+4)*3"` y la convierte a una representación abstracta en forma de árbol sintáctico (de hecho `ast` es de *abstract syntax tree*). El resultado podemos tratarlo en otra función para ir recorriendo ese árbol y realizando las operaciones que indiquen sus nodos, rechazando las que consideremos peligrosas.

Esto es lo que ha hecho el usuario [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs) de Stack Overflow en su excelente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/1264820) a la pregunta ["Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Reproduzco seguidamente su código, que usa la recursividad para lograr su objetivo:

```py
import ast
import operator as op

# supported operators
operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
             ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.Pow: op.pow, ast.BitXor: op.xor,
             ast.USub: op.neg}

def eval_expr(expr):
    """
    >>> eval_expr('2^6')
    4
    >>> eval_expr('2**6')
    64
    >>> eval_expr('1 + 2*3**(4^5) / (6 + -7)')
    -5.0
    """
    return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)

def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num): # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp): # <left> <operator> <right>
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp): # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand))
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Lo revisaré las veces que haga falta hasta comprenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mi mismo, depués de haber estado un mes aprendiendo por mi cuenta jajaja.
He conocido un comando o función llamado "eval". 
Con ella puedo hacer una operación detro de un input, que era lo que yo quería inicialmente. Adjunto el código con el que he hecho el test.

```python
print('Introduce las medidas')
medida = input()
resultado = eval(medida)
print(resultado)
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva esto de algo..

Comment: Gracias por el consejo!!
Si lo que quiero es que se opere con números flotantes, al poner este comando me da error.
`print('Introduce las medidas')
medida = input()
resultado = float(ast.literal_eval(medida))
print(resultado)`