# Calculadora con un Input - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero realizar una calculadora básica en Python3 pero solo he visto que funciona utilizando métodos y condiciones.

Pero es posible que ingresando toda la operación en un Iput, obtener el mismo resultado?

Ejemplo:

```
             input("Ingresa tu operacion: )
                2*5
                10
```

Algo mas o menos así que solo salga un mensaje pidiendo la operación y en automático lo haga .

espero ser claro

Comment: Pues claro, puedes depender de `eval` y estar sujeto a la sintaxis de python o desarrollar algún algoritmo para evaluar expresiones complejas.

Comment: Aunque por el título no lo parezca, esta pregunta trata de lo mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132923/7123 y tiene una respuesta que lo soluciona usando ast.parse ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es revisar cada caracter para identificar el operador. Hice mi propia versión del programa, échale un ojo a ver si te sirve. (OJO: Sólo sirve con un operando)

```
class Operador():
    NOOP = 0
    SUMA = 1
    RESTA = 2
    MULTIPLICACION = 3
    DIVISION = 4

entrada = input()
tamano = len(entrada)

operador = Operador.NOOP
i = 0
while operador == Operador.NOOP or i >= tamano:
    if entrada[i] == '+':
        operador = Operador.SUMA
    elif entrada[i] == '-':
        operador = Operador.RESTA
    elif entrada[i] == '*':
        operador = Operador.MULTIPLICACION
    elif entrada[i] == '/':
        operador = Operador.DIVISION
    i += 1

if(operador != Operador.NOOP):
    argumento1 = float(entrada[0:i-1])
    argumento2 = float(entrada[i:])
    if operador == Operador.SUMA:
        print (argumento1+argumento2)
    elif operador == Operador.RESTA:
        print (argumento1-argumento2)
    elif operador == Operador.MULTIPLICACION:
        print (argumento1*argumento2)
    elif operador == Operador.DIVISION:
        print (argumento1/argumento2)
else:
    print ("No se identifico el operador")
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluar una expresión como mencionas es relativamente sencillo, tal como ya lo mencionó NaCI puedes usar [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) que es funcionalidad base:

```
from math import sqrt

valor = eval("2*3")
print(valor)
> 6

valor = eval("sqrt(4)")
print(valor)
> 2.0
```

Pero `eval()` no evalúa operaciones aritmética evalúa código Python, por consiguiente es una rutina peligrosa, si la vas a ofrecer a un usuario, les estás abriendo la posibilidad de ejecución de cualquier código.

Una solución más acotada es usar algún evaluador matemático, hay varios. Simplemente a modo de ejemplo te puedo sugerir [py-expression-eval](https://github.com/AxiaCore/py-expression-eval)

La instalación, de la forma habitual: `pip install py_expression_eval`

Para ejecutarlo:

```
from py_expression_eval import Parser
parser = Parser()

valor = parser.parse('2 * 3').evaluate({})
print(valor)
```

Verifica en [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), hay evaluadores más simples y otros más complejos, la idea es siempre la misma, ofrecer una evaluación de código más limitada a lo matemático y minimizar los problemas debidos a la ejecución de código indeseado.