# Leer una operacion

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer un programa que me lea una operación y la realice, por ejemplo yo le ingreso:

```
Input
operación=input('Ingrese la operación')
```

> Por ejemplo operación fuera 4/2

```
 Output
 2
```

Lo intente hacer con una entrada que lo tome como cadena y que revise el signo y lo opere como lo hace el sheel cuando ingresamos esto; mi duda es si existe una forma de que ingresandolo de esta forma se opere de una forma efectiva.

Gracias!

Comment: Suele usarse `eval()` por ser lo más simple, pero es peligroso. Mira [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140908/7123) a una pregunta similar.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte  amigo!

Answer (score 1):

el ejemplo que te muestro se auxilia por medio de una función la cual me va a permitir pasar como argumento la operación solicitada, igual esta por anexarse la parte del input pero creo con este ejemplo te muestro como controlar de una manera básica que el usuario elija que operación desea realizar:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def calculadora(option):
    option1 = '+'
    option2 = '-'
    option3 = '*'
    option4 = '/'

    if(option == option1):
        print(1 + 2)
    elif(option == option2):
        print(1 - 2)
    elif(option == option3):
        print(1 * 2)
    elif(option == option4):
        print(1 / 1)
    else:
        print('No reconozco nada')

calculadora('*')
```

Actualización

En el código siguiente en lugar de pasar los números de manera predeterminada declaro dos variables que podrán tomar cualquier valor; los cuales se los paso en forma de argumentos al final dentro de los paréntesis de la función

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def calculadora(option, numero1, numero2):
    option1 = '+'
    option2 = '-'
    option3 = '*'
    option4 = '/'

    if(option == option1):
        print(numero1 + numero2)
    elif(option == option2):
        print(numero1 - numero2)
    elif(option == option3):
        print(numero1 * numero2)
    elif(option == option4):
        print(numero1 / numero2)
    else:
        print('No reconozco nada')

calculadora('*', 2, 30)
```

Ahora si por ejemplo lo que deseas es controlar tanto la operación como los dos números que son ingresados para hacer la operación, te muestro el sigueinte ejemplo que usa el método input para recojer los 3 valores **(claro aún se puede hacer mas por el lado de la validación pero sirve como ejemplo)**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def calculadora():
    option = input("Teclea la operacion: ") 
    numero1 = int(input("Teclea el numero1\n"))
    numero2 = int(input("Teclea el numero2\n"))
    option1 = '+'
    option2 = '-'
    option3 = '*'
    option4 = '/'

    if(option == option1):
        print(numero1 + numero2)
    elif(option == option2):
        print(numero1 - numero2)
    elif(option == option3):
        print(numero1 * numero2)
    elif(option == option4):
        print(numero1 / numero2)
    else:
        print('No reconozco nada')

calculadora()
```

Comment: Hola! pero como hago para que cuando yo ingrese 2**3/3 el me lea todo esto y lo opere.

Comment: bueno es que entonces debes tener mas variables para contener a todos los numeros a los cuales tu deseas operar

Comment: esta respuesta te da el inicio de tu eventual solución, como puedes notar con dos variables numéricas y con algunos el elseif consigo que se haga la selección de la operación, con un poco de paciencia y de aquí partes a lo que necesitas

Comment: checa que por cada operación que yo deseo hacer lo ideal es codificar la lógica de dicha operación o en caso contrario el software no sabrá como responder a las indicaciones

Comment: Vale, estoy resolviendo un problema el cual esta este tipo de entrada como por ejempo '2/3/6' y python debe votar la respuesta

Comment: Pero gracias me distes una mejor idea.

Comment: de nada espero haber sido de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo deberia de poner lo siguiente, lee el caracter que el usuario ponga y suponiendo que sea el signo de "/" deberias de ponerlo dentro de un condicional.

```
signo="/"
if numero == signo:
    operacion = numero1 / numero2;
print(f"El resultado de la division es: {operacion}")
```

Deberias de hacerlo con cada tipo de operacion y si quisieras mas de un numero tendrias que ponerlo en un arreglo y que te sumara, dividiera o restara cada numero que esta dentro del arreglo.

Tambien en el caso de que quisieras poner 4 numeros pero supongamos que quieres  hacer los siguiente (1 + 2 / 3 * 4) el programa deberia de guardar de igual forma en un arreglo el caracter de la operacion, en pocas palabras, pedir un numero y pedir un simbolo de operacion.