# Como Evaluar una expresión sin Data Types

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que realizar un programa que cuando le entre una expresión de la forma `1/2/2` me arroje el resultado correcto que seria 0,25, sin embargo no puedo utilizar alguna función que sea del tipo *eval* o algún *data type*, por lo que recurrí a resolverlo con un while que me recorra la cadena y vaya haciendo la operación, pero Python resuelve las operaciones

> division, multiplicacion resta y suma

con orden de prioridad, es decir las  divisiones primero ante cualquier operación.

Mi duda es como podría yo priorizar las operaciónes y luego realizaras sin utilizar algún *data type* , o si podrían decirme como hace Python internamente esto.

Aqui esta mi codigo que recorre la lista y va operando.

```
from sys import stdin
while True:
    a=[str(i) for i in stdin.readline().strip()]
    if a==[]: break
    b=[]
    var = filter(lambda i: i=='/', a)
    var = "".join(var)
    val=0
    while len(a)>2:
        if a[1]=='*':
            val= (float(a[0])*float(a[2]))
            a=a[2:]
            a[0]=val
        elif a[1]=='+':
            val= (float(a[0])+float(a[2]))
            a=a[2:]
            a[0]=val
        elif a[1]=='/':
            val= (float(a[0])/float(a[2]))
            a=a[2:]
            a[0]=val
        elif a[1]=='-':
            val= (float(a[0])-float(a[2]))
            a=a[2:]
            a[0]=val 


    print(a[0])
```

Comment: Hace un tiempo [respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140908/7123) a un caso similar, con una solución mucho más genérica. Mira a ver si te vale

Comment: Gracias pero no puedo utilizar por desgracia la función eval()

Comment: pero precisamente en esa respuesta se explica que eval no debe usarse y se muestra cómo hacerlo sin eval...

Comment: Tienes razón el modulo ast podría ser la solución a mi problema, pero una duda eso no seria una Data Type, no conozco mucho del tema.

Comment: No, no lo es. Pero tampoco entiendo qué quiere decir esa restricción de no ooder usar data types... no veo qué tienen que ver con eval() o con evaluación de expresiones. Los [Data Types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datatypes.html) son los tipos de datos que trae python. No veo ninguna relación con la pregunta.

Comment: El problema dice lo siguiente: You are not permitted to use python built-in functions that evaluate expressions of any data type, e.g. theeval()function. No estoy seguro de que se puede usar y que no.

Comment: Entiendo que no se te permite usar eval porque ésta puede interpretar cualquier tipo de datos (listas, diccionarios e incluso funciones) precisamente las razones explicadas en mi otra respuesta pr los que eval se considera inseguro. ast no tiene ese problema, pues sólo interprreta literales (numeros)

Comment: Vale ya te entendí, Gracias amigo!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Comment: Hola, Esto no es un trabajo escolar amigo, segundo yo ya he investigado por mi cuenta antes de preguntar, y por último no estoy preguntando para que alguien me haga todo el programa, solo solicito ayuda para el orden de prioridad de las operaciones que es algo que desconozco y por ende no puedo resolver por mi cuenta.