# ¿Cómo pasar una operación en string a uno en número?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo el string de una operación, ejemplo: `resultado ='2+2'`, pero quiero pasarlo a número de modo que me resuelva la ecuación y me de que `resultado=4`. Intente hacer un for en el cual obtenga el índice en el que esta la operación y así guardar el número que esta antes de este como int y operarlo con el número que viene después del índice, pero no me resultó, ya que no opera en el orden que pido, que sería de izquierda a derecha. y no se me ocurre de que otra manera lo podría hacer.

Les agradecería mucho si me pudiesen ayudar.

Esta es la función que se me ocurrió

```
def jota2(algo):
  signo = "+-/*^"
  for i,n in enumerate(algo):
    if n in signo:
      var1=int(algo[0:i])
      if n == '+':
        return var1+jota2(algo[i+1:])
      elif n=='-':
        return var1-jota2(algo[i+1:])
      elif n=='^':
        return var1**jota2(algo[i+1:])
      elif n =='/':
        return var1//jota2(algo[i+1:]) #para obtener un entero
      elif n =='*':
        return var1*jota2(algo[i+1:])
  return int(algo[-1])
```

Comment: Hola! ¿podrías copiar el código de tu intento de for? Eso nos ayudaría un poco a  reproducir el problema o inconveniente, tanto si es conceptual como técnico. Como dice acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Te sirve [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)? `eval('2+2')` da 4, `eval('2+4*3')` da 14

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Evaluar cadena como expresión en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132923/evaluar-cadena-como-expresi%c3%b3n-en-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizas te sirva:

```
sentence = "2+2"

operation=sentence.index("+")

print("operation -", operation)

number1=sentence[operation - 1]

number2=sentence[operation + 1]

print("total: ", (int(number1)+int(number2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

En python puedes usar la funcion `eval();`

```
sentencia= '2+2'

print(eval(sentencia))
```